# javafx putting textarea value into a hashmap

Tags: javafx, hashmap, textarea

I would like to make a small java fx app that has just textarea and one button on a stage and that when you type some strings in textarea and press submit it shows on the stage small table with results how many each Word had occurrences.
so my questions is: does map is the best solution for finding the occurrences even though I do not know what will be the key for finding occurrences and how to connect string from text area, to map.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Word counting");
        TextArea txt=new TextArea();
        txt.setMaxSize(450, 200);
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                primaryStage.hide();
                ShowResults.drugiProzor();
            }
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        root.setTop(txt);
        HBox hbox=new HBox();
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20,20,100,180));
        hbox.getChildren().add(btn);
        root.setBottom(hbox);


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 300);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Word counting!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and the second class is again gui class with table view

```
public class ShowResults {

    static Stage secondaryStage;
    public static void drugiProzor()  {
        secondaryStage=new Stage();
      TableView table=new TableView();

       TableColumn column1=new TableColumn("Word");
        column1.setMinWidth(200);


        TableColumn column2=new TableColumn("Number of occurencies");
        column2.setMinWidth(200);


        table.getColumns().addAll(column1,column2);

      StackPane pane=new StackPane();
      pane.getChildren().add(table);
      Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 450, 300);


        secondaryStage.setScene(scene);
        secondaryStage.setTitle("Counting words");
        secondaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

and third class shoyld be the class where the magic happends something like this:

```
public class Logic {

    public void logic()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do something like

```
public Map<String, Long> countWordOccurences(String text) {
    return Pattern.compile("\\s+") // regular expression matching 1 or more whitespace
        .splitAsStream(text)       // split at regular expression and stream words between
                                   // group by the words themselves and count each group:
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Check the Javadocs to see what each step is doing: [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-), [`Function`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), etc.

If you want to count in a case-insensitive way, you can replace `Function.identity()` with `String::toLowerCase`

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase, Collectors.counting()));
```

and if you want to ignore punctuation, you can add

```
map(s -> s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]",""))
```

to the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me, is this possible to somehow put inside tableview?

Comment: @Pera Umm, yes, just fill the table view with the data from the map.

Comment: i managed to put all of the result in only one line, and i want to have one line one word and number of occurencies/Sorry for  all of this, but i am trying to finish tjis, i am not a programmer, i only know db and sql.Thanks in advance

Comment: how would you apply this to my example, i haven't found anything that is  nearly the same to my example.Sorry for disruption

Comment: @Pera You have the data, just put it in the table.